# Updated Django, getting `The included urlconf Site-main.urls doesn't have any patterns in it` message

Tags: python, django, apache

I recently upgraded from an ancient version of Django to 1.6.8, and now I am getting the error described above inconsistently (more on that below).

I've seen several threads here that discuss this error, and the culprit usually seems to be a view that calls `reverse()` somewhere. However, nothing in any of my views does this.

In fact, I can trim my site's urls.py to just the admin site...

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Site-main.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^Site-main/', include('Site-main.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    # This has to go before the admin site
     url(r'^a/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

...and I still get the error periodically.

"Periodically?"

Well, that's the other really weird thing here. Around half the time the page loads as expected, with no errors. The rest of the time I get the error.

Another odd thing: if I use the manage.py server instead of apache+wsgi, the error seems to go away, *but* I've had the admins completely re-start apache with no change, so I don't think it's just an old and confused httpd process causing the problem.

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: it's weird admin also has this.. thought there is no namespace defined .  !?

Comment: Does it happen if you set DEBUG = False?